# Add new item in second thread - no changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, thread-safety

i try to add new item into my database with Entity Framework but after use SaveChanges() i don't have this item in database.

I have 2 threads in my program and always use using statement to do someting in database. ( I've read that is thread-safety).

Data from table are being displayed in data grid view, and I can see new items after adding, but after close Visual Studio all changes disappear (no changes in database).

My code to add new item:

```
    using (var context = new dbEntities())
        {
                Operation myOperation = new Operation { DateTime = DateTime.Now, DelayTime = 10, RepeatCount = 10, RepeatTime = 10, Type = 10, DayOfWeek = 9999999 };
                context.Operation.Add(myOperation);
                context.SaveChanges();               
        }
```

It's basic and should work, but I don't know why it doesn't work. Can you help me solve this problem, please?

Binding data:

```
     List<Operation> myListOfOperation = new List<Operation>();
        using (var myDb= new dbEntities())
        {
            myListOfOperation = myDb.Operation.ToList();
        }

        m_GridView.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var myTempTask in myListOfOperation)
        {
            m_GridView.Items.Add(myTempTask);
        }
```

I make new object in MainWindow constructor and run new thread in this constructor. 
Funcion in thread:

```
    while (true)
        {
            if (m_OperationInQueue.Count == 0)
            {
                UpdateQueue();
            }
            else if (m_GenerateQueue == true)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5 * 1000);
            }
            else
            {
                TimeSpan myTimeToWait = m_OperationInQueue.First().DateTime - DateTime.Now;
                if (myTimeToWait.TotalMinutes < 0)
                {
                    DoOperation(m_OperationInQueue.First());
                    m_OperationInQueue.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                else if (myTimeToWait.TotalMinutes > 5)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(4 * 60 * 1000);
                }
                else
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(myTimeToWait);
                    DoOperation(m_OperationInQueue.First());
                    m_OperationInQueue.RemoveAt(0);
                }
            }
        }
```

And I try add new item in DoOperation funcion

Comment: is this related to multi-threading or does the not-persisting also occur in STA?

Comment: You need some more details here - you mention multi threading, but provide no code sample illustrating how this fits in, or how you are binding your grid.

Comment: Sorry, I added this details

Comment: Are you sure your database isn't dropped and created between executions?

Comment: Yes i'm sure. I'm using Local Database (.sdf) if it's important.

Comment: once again: is this related to multi-threading or does the not-persisting also occur in STA?